# socket_connect(): unable to connect [10061]

Tags: php, sockets

I'm trying to make a connection with an rls1100 weighing scale using a PHP script, but this error happen:

> Warning: socket_connect(): unable to connect [10061]: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it in C:\xampp\htdocs\ip.php on line 11
>
> Failed to connect to the RLS1100 Label Scale.

and my code is

```php
<?php

// RLS1100 Label Scale IP address and port
$scaleIP = '192.168.1.87';
$scalePort = 9100;

// Create a socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

// Connect to the RLS1100 Label Scale
if (socket_connect($socket, $scaleIP, $scalePort)) {
    echo "Connected to the RLS1100 Label Scale.";
    exit();
    // Send data to the scale
    $data = "Your data to send"; // Replace with your actual data
    socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data));

    // Receive response from the scale
    $response = socket_read($socket, 1024); // Adjust the buffer size as needed
    echo "Response from the scale: " . $response;

    // Close the socket connection
    socket_close($socket);
} else {
    echo "Failed to connect to the RLS1100 Label Scale.";
}

?>
```

Comment: The error means that nothing is listening on that socket on the target IP address. And/or possibly there is a firewall rule somewhere preventing the connection from being made. We can't see your environment, so all we can really do is tell you what the error message means and suggest some common causes...but you could probably have discovered that from a simple google search already.